# How to mock a class in Jasmine

Tags: angular, class, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a class called ClientsListDataSource that I need to simulate, because inside it there are private properties that I can't access in the test.

**clients-list.component.spec.ts**

```
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ],
      declarations: [ ClientsListComponent ],
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ClientService, useValue: clientServiceMock },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ClientsListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    clientServiceMock = TestBed.inject(ClientService);

    component.dataSource = {
      // Here he asks me to define the properties of the class, but some of them are private
    }

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should compile', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**clients-list.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<Client>;
  dataSource!: ClientsListDataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
    this.clientService.list().subscribe(clients => {
      this.dataSource = new ClientsListDataSource();
      this.dataSource.data = clients
      this.dataSource.connect()
    })
  }
```

**error in console**

```
  Error: Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.
```

This error happened because it was not established as properties of the class.

Answer (score 0):

In these sort of cases I think your running into an issue of trying to test far to much at one time. I am assuming that error is being thrown by the `MatTable` child not having some necessary data or the like being passed into itself. I would recommend mocking out `MatPaginator`, `MatSort`, and `MatTable` using dummy components declared in your test context with the same selectors.

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-paginators',
  template: '<p>Mock Paginator Component</p>'
})
class MockMatPaginatorComponent {}
```

Then add this class to your declarations array and remove the imports of the modules. If these are commonly used components in your app you can store these components somewhere else and resuse them here.